# howto make a input box never empty?

Tags: jquery

How can i enforce that an input box cannot be empty, for example: if it's cleared by the user, it shows always "0"

```
  (function ($) {
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $('#value1').keyup(function () { 
    /* something that it has at least '0' as content */
         });
     });
 }(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does it need to be more complicated than this?

```
$('#value1').keyup(function() { 
    if($(this).val() == '')
        $(this).val(0);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(function ($) {
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $('#value1').keyup(function () { 
             if ($('#value1').val() == '') {
                 $('#value1').val(0);
             }
         });
     });
 }(jQuery));
```